# Pip , npm on offline servers

Tags: npm, deployment, pip, virtualenv, web-deployment

If you are developing Python web services for local network (servers is totally offline from the web) and the only way to add files to the server is through Flash drivers so using pip for Python packages or npm for node packages is such a headache and gets in a lot of dependencies issues and build issues .. so what is the proper way of dealing with such environment so development and deployment would be easier?

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 approaches which you can take:

1. download all your dependencies locally and ship them to the remote server. this includes all the pip and npm packages. pay attention to the python\nodejs\operating system versions and architecture.
2. use [docker](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) to create an image, which packs everything. then ship the image to the remote server and finally spin-up a container based on that image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pypicache to run your own pip servers and let it to cache your dependencies wherever you have an internet connection (where you are developing the application).
Then you can copy the whole pypicache folder on your flash drive and run the server wherever you want and use the cached packages inside it. the good point is in some environments that you can get a network connection for a limited time, having a pypicache is useful because it can download whatever all of the dependencies that your python applications need, and each instance would download and install the dependencies from the offline pip server by providing a simple switch in the command line. Here is an example:

```
pip install -i http://localhost:8080/simple somepackage
```

[More Information - pypicache](https://pypicache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)